# How do I close Chrome when entering standby or hibernate?

Tags: google-chrome, security, standby

If I leave Chrome open, it keeps me logged into my sites even during standby, so the only defence I have is my Linux password. I would like to have Chrome shut down on standby or hibernate, and then automatically re-open on resume so that I have to enter my LastPass password when I next use my PC. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I guess that's not a usecase worth implementing in `chrome` because you're account is protected by the display manager/Linux password (absolutely sufficient) and the standby or hibernation should be transparent for any application (that's the purpose of both) including `chrome`.